# Degrees from triangles

Tags: trigonometry, degrees

On my calculator I typed in 90-sin^-1(Y/X)

Y=6, X=9

I was returned with approximately:

48.71 degrees (which I expected)

But on java it returns:

0.72

I was told to use asin on java... Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `asin` method is correct for that.

The result from `asin` is in radians, so you need to convert it to degrees:

```
double angle = 90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(Y / X));
```

Answer (score 0):

trigonometric  functions in programming languages return a value measured in radians. you need to convert to degrees like below.

degrees=radians*180/PI